# Why is my code never detecting any contact with my SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

The problem I am running in to is that the code I created to detect contact is not working. I wanted it to work when the ball category touched the obstacle category. What is wrong with my code? Thank you so much, any help is appreciated!

Heres where I define the categories:

```
let ballCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let obstacleCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
```

Heres where I create the physics aspect of my ball:

```
    leftBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftBall.size)
    leftBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
    leftBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory
    leftBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    leftBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    leftBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

Heres where I create the physics aspect of an obstacle:

```
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: obstacleSquare.size)
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    obstacleSquare.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
```

And heres my collision detection function:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    print("CONTACT")

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == obstacleCategory {

        print("CONTACT")
        gameOver()

    }

    if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == obstacleCategory {

        print("CONTACT")
        gameOver()

    }

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballCategory {

        print("CONTACT")
        gameOver()

    }

    if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ballCategory {

        print("CONTACT")
        gameOver()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your object’s physics bodies have their `isDynamic` Property set to false.  At least one of them needs to have this property set to true for any contacts to be registered.